# Scanner in for loop, loops once before getting any input

Tags: java, for-loop

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String in;
    int count = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        System.out.print("Input "+i+" of "+count+": ");
        in = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

As the title says, this for loop prints the line twice (with the "i" variable incremented once) before it stops to wait for user input. I don't understand why it does that. I tried to use while loop, with similar results. Help?

Comment: add a simple scan.next(); or scan.nextLine(); after your scan.nextInt(); and before your loop. or read a String in the first statement, and parse it to an int.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `scan.nextLine();` after `scan.Int();`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String in;
int count = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String in;
int count = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    System.out.print("Input "+i+" of "+count+": ");
    in = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Keep in mind, you need to handle NaN exception

---

Alternative, as suggested by @Stultuske in a comment, add `scan.nextLine();` or `scan.next();` after `scan.nextInt();`